# Call program from subprocess.Popen in python: `OSError: .. No such file or directory`

Tags: python, subprocess

I run the following command from my bash script:

```
myProgram --name test1 --index 0
```

But now I want to run it from within a python script so I have tried the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from threading import Thread
import time
import subprocess

print "hello Python"

subprocess.Popen("myProgram --name test1 --index 0")
```

But I get the error:

```
hello Python
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./myPythonProgram.py", line 8, in <module>
subprocess.Popen("myProgram --name test1 --index 0")
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1141, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Is the correct way to call this??

Comment: `subprocess.Popen("myProgram --name test1 --index 0", shell=True)`. or `subprocess.Popen(['myProgram', '--name', '1', '--index', '0'])`

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the command as a list:

```
subprocess.Popen("myProgram --name test1 --index 0".split())
```

**Edit:**

`str.split()` would not take into account the shell metacharacters/tokens, hence is insecure. You should use `shlex.split()` instead:

```
import shlex

command = shlex.split("myProgram --name test1 --index 0")
subprocess.Popen(command)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass it as a `list` or you need to give an argument as `shell=True`

Try this:

```
output = subprocess.Popen("myProgram --name test1 --index 0", shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
out, err = output.communicate()

print(out)
```

The `universal_newlines` argument gives you output as a string without changing a newline in your output to a `\n`.

If you don't want to store the output in a variable and just want to get the output in the console, try `subprocess.call()` or, `subprocess.run()` if you have **Python 3.5**